# Is there a better way to declare a char-type appropriate instance of a CStringT<> than

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, atl

What I am trying to get at is a function that generates an instance of a CStringT<> that is appropriate for a given type of character (char or wchar_t).

Here's a contrived example:

```
#include <atlstr.h>

template <typename CHAR_T>
inline 
CStringT< CHAR_T, ATL::StrTraitATL< CHAR_T, ATL::ChTraitsCRT< CHAR_T > > >
AsCString(const CHAR_T * psz)
{
  return CStringT< CHAR_T, ATL::StrTraitATL< CHAR_T, ATL::ChTraitsCRT< CHAR_T > > >(psz);
}
```

I can certainly use the above (it appears to compile), but it would be a lot nicer for readers of my code (and probably for future compatibility) if I could use something like:

```
ATL::make_cstring(psz);
```

Is anyone aware of such a utility, or anything like it?

Comment: People are still writing new code using CString?  Bleh!

Comment: To try to clarify: the above works, but I have had to supply way too many arguments for my liking.  What I really want is to say CStringT<CHAR_T>.  But that fails to compile, since the underlying CString<> doesn't supply default types for the rest of its arguments, so I'm saying a lot more than I really want to (and I'm not sure that it makes sense for other projects which don't necessarily use the CRT (ChTraitsCRT)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You, everyone who helped out with this.

Here is the answer that most completely answers my needs:

```
// generates the correct CString type based on char_T
template <typename charT>
struct cstring_type
{
    // compile time error if no matching CStringT<> for charT
};

template <>
struct cstring_type<char>
{
    typedef CStringA type;
};

template <>
struct cstring_type<wchar_t>
{
    typedef CStringW type;
};

#define CSTRINGTYPE(T) typename cstring_type<T>::type

// returns an instance of a CStringA or CStringW based on the given char_T
template <typename charT>
inline CSTRINGTYPE(charT) make_cstring(const charT * psz)
{
    return psz;
}
```

As you can see, it fully generates the correct CString type (either CStringA or CStringW) based entirely upon the template parameter (charT).  This version has the added advantage of not trying to explicitly generate a CStringT<...> which depends on further compile time options (such as using CRT, using MFC, etc.).  Instead, it results in the system-supplied CStringA or CStringW, which Microsoft maintains, hence giving my code greater flexibility and future-proofing it (as much as can be gained, I expect).

Answer (score 2):

It's already there, use either CString (project setting), CStringA or CStringW.  After 17+ years of Unicode and operating systems that are exclusively Unicode, there are *very* few reasons left to avoid getting the project setting right.

Comment: There are any number of times when it is necessary to deal with strings of both narrow and wide characters in a single project.  For example: reading/write legacy files (narrow). I/O to a serial device (yes those still exist: see flat-bed plotters & samplemakers). etc.

Comment: Device I/O is in bytes.  Little point in converting to 8-bit strings, then bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I understand it correctly, you want to create a string based on the type of char (char /Wchar_t)

```
template <typename _T>
CStringT <_T, ATL::StrTraitATL <_T, ATL::ChTraitsCRT <_T > > >
make_cstring (_T* __args)
{
 .. create cstring and return it
}
```

Comment: Please use the '010101' button to format code.  I've done this for you here.

Comment: Basically.  The template I posted in my OP does this.  The question part is "do I really need to be rolling my own, or is there already such a facility hidden away in the miles of ATL code that I can just use, which Microsoft would maintain, so that it is correct in foreseeable future versions of their compiler?"

Answer (score -1):

Don't use all caps for non-macro purposes.

Why not just stick it in the ATL namespace and call it make_cstring? (hell, why not just use std::string?)

Comment: ATL is the namespace name that Microsoft chose - it is not my doing.

Comment: std::string is valuable, but it has its limits.  One of which is that it is not plug-in compatible with the reams of code that we've already got which uses CString, which has no real downsides, therefore, little or no motivation to rewrite & redebug for the sole purpose of pleasing language purists.

Comment: @Mordachai: I was referring to the template parameter, not the namespace name, and I was genuinely curious, as opposed to OMG YOU SHOULD USE STD STRING!

Comment: @Mordachai:  You mentioned portability.  Good luck getting CString to compile in g++

Comment: @DeadMG I was probably a bit hasty - I apologize for assuming your tone was of the OMGBBQ variety :(