# C++ String-type independent algorithms

Tags: c++, templates, mfc

I'm trying to derive a technique for writing string-algorithms that is truly independent of the underlying type of string.

Background: the prototypes for GetIndexOf and FindOneOf are either overloaded or templated variations on:

```
int GetIndexOf(const char * pszInner, const char * pszString);
const char * FindOneOf(const char * pszString, const char * pszSetOfChars);
```

This issue comes up in the following template function:

```
// return index of, or -1, the first occurrence of any given char in target
template <typename T>
inline int FindIndexOfOneOf(const T * str, const T * pszSearchChars)
{
    return GetIndexOf(FindOneOf(str, pszSearchChars), str);
}
```

Objectives:
 1. I would like this code to work for CStringT<>, const char *, const wchar_t * (and should be trivial to extend to std::string)
 2. I don't want to pass anything by copy (only by const & or const *)

In an attempt to solve these two objectives, I thought I might be able to use a type-selector of sorts to derive the correct interfaces on the fly:

```
namespace details {

    template <typename T>
    struct char_type_of
    {
        // typedef T type; error for invalid types (i.e. anything for which there is not a specialization)
    };

    template <>
    struct char_type_of<const char *>
    {
        typedef char type;
    };

    template <>
    struct char_type_of<const wchar_t *>
    {
        typedef wchar_t type;
    };

    template <>
    struct char_type_of<CStringA>
    {
        typedef CStringA::XCHAR type;
    };

    template <>
    struct char_type_of<CStringW>
    {
        typedef CStringW::XCHAR type;
    };

}

#define CHARTYPEOF(T) typename details::char_type_of<T>::type
```

Which allows:

```
template <typename T>
inline int FindIndexOfOneOf(T str, const CHARTYPEOF(T) * pszSearchChars)
{
    return GetIndexOf(FindOneOf(str, pszSearchChars), str);
}
```

This should guarantee that the second argument is passed as const  *, and should not determine T (rather only the first argument should determine T).

But the problem with this approach is that T, when str is a CStringT<>, is a copy of the CStringT<> rather than a reference to it: hence we have an unnecessary copy.

Trying to rewrite the above as:

```
template <typename T>
inline int FindIndexOfOneOf(T & str, const CHARTYPEOF(T) * pszSearchChars)
{
    return GetIndexOf(FindOneOf(str, pszSearchChars), str);
}
```

Makes it impossible for the compiler (VS2008) to generate a correct instance of FindIndexOfOneOf<> for:

```
FindIndexOfOneOf(_T("abc"), _T("def"));
    error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'int FindIndexOfOneOf(T &,const details::char_type_of<T>::type *)'
    With the following template arguments: 'const char [4]'
```

This is a generic problem I've had with templates since they were introduced (yes, I'm that old): That it's been essentially impossible to construct a way to handle both old C-style arrays and newer class based entities (perhaps best highlighted by const char [4] vs. CString<> &).

The STL/std library "solved" this issue (if one can really call it solving) by instead using pairs of iterators everywhere instead of a reference to the thing itself.  I could go this route, except it sucks IMO, and I don't want to have to litter my code with two-arguments everywhere a single argument properly handled should have been.

Basically, I'm interested in an approach - such as using some sort of stringy_traits - that would allow me to write GetIndexOfOneOf<> (and other similar template functions) where the argument is the string (not a pair of (being, end] arguments), and the template that is then generated be correct based on that string-argument-type (either **const  *** or **const CString<> &**).

So the Question: **How might I write FindIndexOfOneOf<> such that its arguments can be any of the following without ever creating a copy of the underlying arguments:**
 1. FindIndexOfOneOf(_T("abc"), _T("def"));
 2. CString str; FindIndexOfOneOf(str, _T("def"));
 3. CString str; FindIndexOfOneOf(T("abc"), str);
 3. CString str; FindIndexOfOneOf(str, str);

Related threads to this one that have lead me to this point:

> [A better way to declare a char-type appropriate CString<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261418/is-there-a-better-way-to-declare-a-char-type-appropriate-instance-of-a-cstringt)
>   [Templated string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261673/templates-and-string-literals-and-unicode)

Comment: Personal preference.  I already know how to do that, I find it ugly, and I would like to see if there is a genuinely smarter approach.

Comment: Part of the reason to avoid using iterators (besides personal pref) is that I already have a lot of client code which expects to be able to pass CStrings & const char *s.  So I would have to update a prohibitive amount of client code.  At that point, it makes more sense to write two versions of each function, for narrow & wide, and allow automatic type casting to coerce CString's to const <char> *s.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
#include <type_traits>
inline int FindIndexOfOneOf(T& str, const typename char_type_of<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type* pszSearchChars)
```

The problem is that when you make the first argument a reference type T becomes deduced as:

```
const char []
```

but you want

```
const char*
```

You can use the following to make this conversion.

```
std::decay<T>::type
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361638.aspx) says.

```
If is_array<U>::value is true, the modified-type type is remove_extent<U>::type *.
```

Comment: This solution relies on VS 2010 (which has the newer provisional version of the std library for C++0x).  I'm currently still on 2008 (but I assume this comes from boost anyway, which I can use).

Comment: type_traits are included in tr1 which works for visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boost's [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) and [type_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) for this:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

// Just for convenience
using boost::enable_if;
using boost::disable_if;
using boost::is_same;

// Version for C strings takes param #1 by value
template <typename T>
inline typename enable_if<is_same<T, const char*>, int>::type
FindIndexOfOneOf(T str, const CHARTYPEOF(T) * pszSearchChars)
{
    return GetIndexOf(FindOneOf(str, pszSearchChars), str);
}

// Version for other types takes param #1 by ref
template <typename T>
inline typename disable_if<is_same<T, const char*>, int>::type
FindIndexOfOneOf(T& str, const CHARTYPEOF(T) * pszSearchChars)
{
    return GetIndexOf(FindOneOf(str, pszSearchChars), str);
}
```

You should probably expand the first case to handle both `char` and `wchar_t` strings, which you can do using [`or_` from Boost's MPL library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/or.html).

I would also recommend making the version that takes a reference take a const reference instead.  This just avoids instantiation of 2 separate versions of the code (as it stands, `T` will be inferred as a const type for const objects, and a non-const type for non-const objects; changing the parameter type to `T const& str` means `T` will always be inferred as a non-const type).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments about iterators it seems you've not fully considered options you may have.  I can't do anything about personal preference, but then again...IMHO it shouldn't be a formidable obstacle to overcome in order to accept a reasonable solution, which should be weighed and balanced *technically*.

```
template < typename Iter >
void my_iter_fun(Iter start, Iter end)
{
 ...
}
template < typename T >
void my_string_interface(T str)
{
  my_iter_fun(str.begin(), str.end());
}
template < typename T >
void my_string_interface(T* chars)
{
  my_iter_fun(chars, chars + strlen(chars));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to my previous answer, if you don't want to install tr1.

Add the following template specializations to cover the deduced T type when the first argument is a reference.

```
template<unsigned int N>
struct char_type_of<const wchar_t[N]>
{ 
    typedef wchar_t type;
};

template<unsigned int N>
struct char_type_of<const char[N]>
{ 
    typedef char type;
};
```